# Split activity into multiple files

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm writing an android application, which has one activity, which contains several fragments. Now I want to know is there a way to split that activity into several files - to have separate file for each fragment?

For making my question clearer here is structure of my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment2();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment3();
                case 3:
                    return new Fragment4();
            }
        }

    public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment {}

    public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {}

    public static class Fragment3 extends Fragment {}

    public static class Fragment4 extends Fragment {}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to know is there a way to split that activity into several files - to have separate file for each fragment

If the above means that you recently got all your Fragments as inner classes within your Activity class, then answer is `yes` - just create separate `java` class file for each fragment.